# gstreamer x264enc Output File Size vs resolution altered by videoscale

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

My question pertains to output filesize relative to videoscale.

I'm in the process of augmenting an existing Rust application I'm writing to stream media attached to arbitrary data entities. In preparation for rolling the code, I'm trying to workout a gstreamer pipeline that will take a source input file and output a handful of h264 encoded video/AAC encoded audio mp4 files as well as their HLS equivalents. As part of that process, I'm working on a initial `gst-launch-1.0` pipeline, as follows:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e filesrc location=video.mov ! \
decodebin name=decode ! tee name=raw_stream \
decode. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! avenc_aac ! tee name=encoded_audio \
raw_stream. ! queue ! videoscale ! 'video/x-raw,width=400,height=224' ! x264enc ! queue ! mp4mux name=224mux ! filesink location=video400x224.mp4 \
raw_stream. ! queue ! videoscale ! 'video/x-raw,width=640,height=360' ! x264enc ! queue ! mp4mux name=360mux ! filesink location=video640x360.mp4 \
raw_stream. ! queue ! videoscale ! 'video/x-raw,width=960,height=540' ! x264enc ! queue ! mp4mux name=540mux ! filesink location=video960x540.mp4 \
raw_stream. ! queue ! videoscale ! 'video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720' ! x264enc ! queue ! mp4mux name=720mux ! filesink location=video1280x720.mp4 \
raw_stream. ! queue ! videoscale ! 'video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080' ! x264enc ! queue ! mp4mux name=1080mux ! filesink location=video1920x1080.mp4 \
encoded_audio. ! queue ! 224mux. \
encoded_audio. ! queue ! 360mux. \
encoded_audio. ! queue ! 540mux. \
encoded_audio. ! queue ! 720mux. \
encoded_audio. ! queue ! 1080mux.
```

Running the aforementioned successfully outputs a variety of videos of various resolution, with audio properly sync'd. However, I would expect the output file size to scale based based on resolution, if I understand correctly. This is not the case. I initially thought the audio might be to blame, as the audio should be consistent across all resolutions, but removing the audio portion from the pipeline resulted in smaller files, but was consistent with the prior result.

As an example, with audio the following was the resulting size of the output files:

```
Source Video: 1920x1080 resolution size: 171.6MB

Resulting Files:
1) video400x224.mp4 <- 20.3MB
2) video640x360.mp4 <- 19.7MB
3) video960x540.mp4 <- 20.7MB
4) video1280x720.mp4 <- 19.2MB
5) video1920x1080.mp4 <- 17.6MB
```

That is certainly an excellent decrease in size realized from the original encoding. However, as you can see above, the highest resolution encoded file, which matches the resolution of the source file, was the smallest.

Are there any thoughts on this? I'm experimenting with various quality properties on the x264enc plugin, but haven't found anything concrete yet to resolve this.

Any help or thoughts is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to boil down to the relationship between bitrate and filesize and the default x264enc plugin settings. You can tune with:

`bitrate=XXXX` and `pass=`.